What if the current US president dies after the next president is elected but before inauguration?
According to the US law, the vice president could succeed to the presidency without need of election if the current one dies.
Thus, could Kamala Harris become president if Joseph Biden dies, even though Donald Trump has won the election?
Then what would happen to Donald Trump's presidency?
Would he inaugurate after Harris' term?

I'm not sure whether you are asking if Donald Trump could become the President prior to January 20 (there is a convoluted path toward that outcome) or if Harris becoming President due to presidential succession rules gives her another four years (the answer is no). The convoluted path, which isn't going to happen, is (1) Mike Johnson resigns as Speaker of the House, (2) the House elects Donald Trump as Speaker, and (3) both Joseph Biden and Kamala Harris resign. Something like that almost happened in 1916, but never came to pass as Woodrow Wilson narrowly won reelection.

@DavidHammen Someone proposed a conspiracy theory that Democrats would take extraordinary measures to reverse the defeat in the election by exploiting the succession rules. I believe that the US constitution can't be such buggy though. So I wish to know how it closes the loophole.

While the Constitution is intentionally vague at times, it is quite clear regarding presidential succession and transition. A person who attains the presidency via succession fills out the term of the person who was elected to office. There is no extension. The Constitution is quite clear on that. These conspiracy theories oftentimes are just nuts.

I guess you're too young to remember Gerald Ford's presidency after Nixon resigned. It ended when Nixon's term would have ended, not 4 years after rhe resignation.

Also, as with Nixon, Biden wouldn't have to die -- if the loophole actually existed, he could just resign.

A non-presidential version of this happened in Georgia's 5th congressional district in 2020 after  representative John Lewis died on July 17. Nikema Williams replaced Lewis on the November 3 ballot and won with 301,857 votes, but only with effect from January 3, 2021.  Meanwhile there was a special election to fill the vacancy until then, held on September 29, 2020 with a runoff vote on December 1 won by Kwanza Hall with 13,450 votes.  So Hall only served for a month (including the holiday season).

Uhm, Kamala has no term. Even IF Biden dies, she does not get her own (full) term or anything like that. She just takes over for the remaining duration of Bidens term.

@Hobbamok - yes, that's the cleanest way to think of it. And this also relates to the two-term restrictions... even if a VP ended up serving all but a day or two of an inherited presidential term, this doesn't count towards their ability to be elected president twice.

@SimonGeard So technically, if the next president after Trump chooses Trump as VP, and they resign/die/whatever reason to leave the spot, Trump can become president again? And possibly repeat again afterwards (highly unlikely, but hypothetical).

@Alsein if such a loophole existed it would allow for the party in government to extend their rule indefinitely provided they have a majority in congress (to confirm a new VP pick) at some point before the running four-year term ran out. It's so absurdly exploitable it's laughable that people believe it could exist

@SimonGeard The 22nd Amendment says that if you acted as President for more than 2 years you can only be elected once. So 2+ years essentially counts as if you were elected. E.g. Ford could only have been elected once.

Donald Trump is the President-Elect and presumably* will become the President on the 20th of January, 2025, as dictated by the 20th Amendment to the US Constitution. The death or incapacitation of President Biden does not change that date. Should that happen, Kamala Harris, as the sitting Vice President would become the President for a brief period of time -- until January 20. That will be when Donald Trump (assuming he is still alive at that point) takes the reins of power.
* I wrote "presumably" because the votes have not yet been certified, the Electoral College has not yet met, and Congress has not yet certified the Electoral College results (this happens on January 6). Also, we don't know whether Donald Trump will live until noon on January 20. Presumably he will live to that date. If he doesn't, it will be JD Vance who becomes President on noon on January 20.
Edited to clarify:

Thus, could Kamala Harris become president if Joseph Biden dies, even though Donald Trump has won the election?

Kamala Harris would become President at the time of Joseph Biden passing and continue in that capacity until noon on January 20.

Then what would happen to Donald Trump's presidency? Would he inaugurate after Harris' term?

Should that happen, Kamala Harris' term would end at noon on January 20. Donald Trump would still become President on January 20. There is nothing in the Constitution or in US law that makes the President-elect become President earlier than planned -- or later than planned.

Of note, this would mean that Trump would become the 48th President, not the 47th.  There's no meaningful difference there, but it does mean that anything already created calling him the 47th would then have to be updated.

Concerning your "fine print":  if a candidate dies between Election Day and when electors meet in December, it's not entirely clear what would happen. The last time that happened, when the losing candidate died in late November 1872, the electors split their vote between four different candidates.  There are faithless electors laws nowadays that might affect things as well.  That said, if Trump died tomorrow the most likely outcome would presumably be that his electors would cast their ballots for Vance — but it's another "presumably" to add to the pile.

@MichaelSeifert which is probably one reason the president elect is already filling in his positions for speaker of the house and senate majority leader, and his cabinet positions as well as those people are on the succession list were both the president elect and vice president elect to die.

@jwenting:  I don't think cabinet members are on the succession list until they actually take their positions, which doesn't happen until they're confirmed by the Senate in 2025.  Also, the president-elect doesn't choose the Speaker of the House or the Senate majority leader;  the respective houses do.  (Though, of course, the once & future president can lobby congresspersons to elect his preferred candidate.)

@MichaelSeifert not normally, but given the extremely rare and disastrous scenario we're dealing with here (complete eradication of the succession hierarchy in an inter-regnum period) I'm sure they want as much in place as possible, if the whole idea is even on their mind.

@jwenting - While I'm sure his stature with his party is enough that his wishes on the matter may well be respected, Speaker of the House and Senate Majority leader are internal matters to those bodies, and not appointees of the POTUS. I don't know that I've ever heard of a President directly involving himself in the decision-making process on those internally-elected positions (and if he is, it seems like a bad sign).

I think the problem is the idea that Harris gets a term in office at all. She doesn't - she merely inherits the remainder of Biden's term. And this matches up nicely to the idea that you can't be elected president more than twice... an inherited term, even if it ended up being most of a four-year term, doesn't prevent you from standing for two further elected terms.

@SimonGeard Slight correction: if you serve more than two years of an inherited term, you can only be elected to one more term. (Though this obviously doesn't matter for the scenario in the question.)

@DLosc Ah, my mistake...


Someone proposed a conspiracy theory that Democrats would take extraordinary measures to reverse the defeat in the election by exploiting the succession rules. I believe that the US constitution can't be such buggy though. So I wish to know how it closes the loophole.

There's no loophole.  Biden's term ends at noon on January 20th, 2025.  If Biden does not complete the term for any reason, Kamala Harris will become president until the end of the term.  If she is unavailable to do so, or if she leaves office for any reason, the succession rules established by statute will be used to decide who will become president -- for the remainder of the term that ends at noon on January 20th, 2025.
The term for which Donald Trump has been elected (pending completion of the formalities) lasts from that time until noon on January 20th, 2029.  If Trump is unable to become president or leaves office before the end of the term for any reason, the office will pass to J. D. Vance, then to the line of succession.
At this point, the only way a Democrat could be sworn in to the presidency on January 20th would be for Trump and Vance both to be dead, disqualified, or persuaded to resign, and then for one of the following two things to happen:

The House of Representatives elects a democratic speaker, who would be next in the line of succession, or
If the House of Representatives is controlled by the Republican party, the speaker of the House and the president pro tempore of the Senate are also, somehow, both disqualified or persuaded not to assume office, and the line of succession passes to the cabinet, who would still be Biden appointees unless they had all resigned -- and surely if Democrats were actually well enough coordinated to conspire to remove the president elect, the vice president elect, and two other people from the line of succession, they would also make sure their preferred president would not have resigned.


You answered the question after the OP clarified they were asking about a kooky conspiracy theory. The rules on presidential succession and presidential transition are orthogonal. The Constitution (including amendments) is very clear on that. I haven't the foggiest idea how these very kooky conspiracy theories arise. There is no loophole.

@DavidHammen I don't understand your comment.  The tone seems to be one of disagreement, but the substance essentially restates the answer, and the comment's last sentence is the same as the answer's first.

" If she is unavailable to do so, or if she leaves office for any reason, the succession rules established by statute will be used to decide who will become president -- for the remainder of the term" Nitpick: in that case the person will "act" as President, but not "become" President.

@phoog Your answer is obviously addressing a clarifying comment by the OP as you quoted that clarifying comment verbatim. I had asked for a clarification because I wasn't sure what the OP was asking, but I asked for the clarification after I wrote my answer. Regarding your answer, there is no disagreement with your answer on my part; as you wrote, there is no loophole, period. Regarding the clarifying comment by the OP, I simply do not understand where or how these obviously wrongheaded conspiracy theories arise and spread.

@DavidHammen maybe ask a question about this?

@PaŭloEbermann A question about how/why conspiracy theories are so rampant? No thanks.

@DavidHammen the world is full of weird conspiracy theories born out of a misunderstanding or partial misunderstanding of how things work. It makes sense (kinda) to think "if the president dies the VP becomes president, the president serves 4 years, so Kamala would be president for 4 years". It doesn't work like that but I can fully understand someone with very limited knowledge of the actual workings of presidential succession to think so. I've heard similarly bizarre ideas about how Trump was going to become president for life through a loophole, don't remember the details.

@DavidHammen How these obviously wrongheaded conspiracy theories arise and spread? Well, we all try to make sense of the world; some of us are just not very good at it ;-).

@DavidHammen And we know that because the filters preventing distribution of off-mainstream opinions until roughly the mid-oughts have gone for good. Because almost nobody is actually mainstream, this new open marketplace of ideas was initially heralded as progress, from the left and right alike; alas, the emerging variance of opinions seems larger than anticipated, with many outside the sanity interval.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica It doesn't help that 21% of adults in the US are functionally illiterate.

@DavidHammen True.

I have doubts/concerns over the proposed methods for a Democrat to get into office — primarily on the basis that the Electoral College has not yet voted. If Trump & Vance both died (or otherwise became ineligible) before that date, then the Line of Succession would not yet apply: the Electors would have to choose different people for the Presidency. The question is, could they pick new Republican candidates not on the original ballots (being that the state votes technically picked Republican Electors, not directly Trump) or would they be 'expected' to pick the runners-up? (i.e. Kamala & Walz)

@Chronocidal some states at least have laws governing the electors, for example penalizing them if they don't honor the pledge they made to vote for a particular candidate.  If the candidate is no longer alive (or has withdrawn or what have you) then these penalties presumably do not apply, but the details will be different from state to state.  Whether any of these laws impose further restrictions on whom they can vote for in such circumstances, I do not know, but if there are such restrictions they are more likely to require them to vote for someone of the same party.

@Chronocidal there's no reason to think that they would have to be limited to the declared candidates; it would lead to an undemocratic result.  In thinking that they would be so limited, you may be thinking of the procedure for further voting in Congress if no candidate has a majority of electoral college votes: in that case, the House of Representatives chooses between the three candidates with the highest number of votes in the electoral college.  But as far as the constitution is concerned, electors can vote for anyone.

@DavidHammen This conspiracy theory was from a Chinese social media. Most people in Chinese social media simply regard Democrats as unscrupulous conspirators, and there was an article saying that Joseph Biden was abandoned by the Democratic Party.

@DavidHammen "there is no disagreement with your answer on my part": in that case, I apologize for misapprehending the tone.  "Your answer is obviously addressing a clarifying comment by the OP": in part, yes, but in addition, I had been contemplating whether to add an answer, and reading that comment tipped the scales in favor of doing so, since it's one thing to ask how the process works, but it is another thing to frame the question in terms of a loophole when none exists.

@Chronocidal At least for the two major parties (and third parties don't win elections), the electors are selected by the candidates (or their surrogates). The states then appoint the states' electors to the candidate who won the state election (or, in the case of Nebraska and Maine, one elector for each congressional district plus two electors statewide). There is zero chance those electors selected by the Trump campaign would  ever vote for Harris-Walz, under any circumstances. Getting to 270 electoral votes might be problematic should both Trump and Vance die or resign.
